# Writing characteristic failed error when writing to ESP32 GATT characteristic using protobufjs and ionic capacitor BLE plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, protocol-buffers, capacitor, protobuf.js

Building Android app from Angular (using Ionic) to scan a BLE device (ESP32 chip) and write to its GATT characteristic. Using Capacitor BLE plug-in for BLE communication and protobufjs to create message (since ESP32 code uses Google's Protocol Buffer mechanism to accept messages).  App deployed on Samsung Galaxy Tab A7 to deploy app.  Get "Writing characteristic failed" error message when executing BLEClient.write and can't understand why it's failing.  Here's my code (getBLE() invoked when user clicks a button):

```
import { load } from '../../../node_modules/protobufjs';
import { BleClient } from '@capacitor-community/bluetooth-le';

export class SetupPage implements OnInit {

  async getBLE(){
    try {
      let wifiid = 'wifiSSID';
      let password = 'somePassword';
      await load ('../../assets/wifi_config.proto')
      .then((root) => {
        var wifi_config_message = root.lookupType("wifi_config_package.CmdSetConfig");
        let message = wifi_config_message.create({
          ssid: wifiid,
          passphrase: password
        });
        let buffer1 = wifi_config_message.encode(message).finish();
        return buffer1;
      })
      .then(async buffer1 => {
        await BleClient.initialize();
        let connectedDevice = await BleClient.requestDevice();
        await BleClient.connect(connectedDevice.deviceId);
        let bufferView = await new DataView(buffer1.buffer);
        const result = await BleClient.write(connectedDevice.deviceId, '021a9004-0382-4aea-bff4-6b3f1c5adfb4', '021aff52-0382-4aea-bff4-6b3f1c5adfb4',bufferView);
      });
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log('bluetooth error is: ', error);
    }
  }
}
```

This is what the wifi_config.proto file looks like:

```
package wifi_config_package;
syntax = "proto3";

import "constants.proto";
import "wifi_constants.proto";

message CmdGetStatus {}

message RespGetStatus {
    Status status = 1;
    WifiStationState sta_state = 2;
    oneof state {
        WifiConnectFailedReason fail_reason = 10;
        WifiConnectedState connected = 11;
    }
}

message CmdSetConfig {
    string ssid = 1;
    string passphrase = 2;
    bytes bssid = 3;
    int32 channel = 4;
}

message RespSetConfig {
    Status status = 1;
}

message CmdApplyConfig {}

message RespApplyConfig {
    Status status = 1;
}

enum WiFiConfigMsgType {
    TypeCmdGetStatus = 0;
    TypeRespGetStatus = 1;
    TypeCmdSetConfig = 2;
    TypeRespSetConfig = 3;
    TypeCmdApplyConfig = 4;
    TypeRespApplyConfig = 5;
}

message WiFiConfigPayload {
    WiFiConfigMsgType msg = 1;
    oneof payload {
        CmdGetStatus cmd_get_status = 10;
        RespGetStatus resp_get_status = 11;
        CmdSetConfig cmd_set_config = 12;
        RespSetConfig resp_set_config = 13;
        CmdApplyConfig cmd_apply_config = 14;
        RespApplyConfig resp_apply_config = 15;
    }
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?  Any alternatives to achieve the same objective (send data over BLE to ESP32 by writing to GATT characteristic)?  I'd prefer not to resort to native Android app development since I have no experience with it and am on a short deadline.  Also, not very comfortable with Protocol Buffer mechanism, so some guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by using Google's protocol buffer code for javascript.  Couldn't figure out how to create the correct message format using protobufjs.create, especially since the message needed to mimic a nested object.  Here's code that worked for me:

```
import * as goog from 'google-protobuf';
export class SetupPage implements OnInit {

  messages = require('../../assets/proto-js/wifi_config_pb.js');
  connectedDevice: BleDevice;
  bleScan: any;
  wifiSSID: Promise<any>;
  scanResults: Promise<[]>;
  wifiCredentials: string;
  uint8String: Uint8Array;
  buffer: Uint8Array;

  ngOnInit() {
    async getBLE(){
      await BleClient.initialize();
      var cmdSetMessage = new this.messages.CmdSetConfig();
      var wifiConfigPayloadMessage = new this.messages.WiFiConfigPayload;
      message.setSsid('wifiid');
      message.setPassphrase('password');
      wifiConfigPayloadMessage.setCmdSetConfig(cmdSetMessage);
      wifiConfigPayloadMessage.setMsg(2);
      let bytesOfStuff = await wifiConfigPayloadMessage.serializeBinary();
      this.connectedDevice = await BleClient.requestDevice();
      await BleClient.connect(this.connectedDevice.deviceId);
      BleClient.writeWithoutResponse(this.connectedDevice.deviceId, '021a9004-0382- 
      4aea-bff4-6b3f1c5adfb4', '021aff52-0382-4aea-bff4-6b3f1c5adfb4', 
      bytesOfStuff)
  }
}
```

Before this code can function, you need to install google-protobuf from npm or other package installer and protoc or another compiler for the proto files in order to generate pb.js files (since I'm working with javascript) for each proto file.  In this example, the proto file is called wifi_config.proto, and the corresponding pb.js file (created by running protoc) is called wifi_config_pb.js.

Functions used to create the data to be transferred are defined in the pb.js files and correspond to objects defined in the proto files.  The following references will help a lot if you don't have a good understanding of how this mechanism works:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3 (google protocol-buffer tutorial)

[Protocol Buffers in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316223/protocol-buffers-in-ionic) (stack question)

PM me if you have any questions.